# How to save hex representation of binary file into a std::string?

Tags: c++, string, hex, fstream, stringstream

I have used this solution [(c++) Read .dat file as hex using ifstream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16410362/c-read-dat-file-as-hex-using-ifstream/16410748#16410748) but instead of printing it to `std::cout` I would like to save binary file's hex representation to a `std::string`

```
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  unsigned char x; 

  std::ifstream fin(argv[1], std::ios::binary);
  std::stringstream buffer;

  fin >> std::noskipws;
  while (!fin.eof()) {
    fin >> x ; 
    buffer << std::hex << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << static_cast<int>(x);
  }
  std::cout << buffer;
}
```

Printing to `cout` works but saving those contents to `buffer` and then trying to print it to `cout` prints garbage.

What am I missing?

Comment: `std::cout << buffer.str();`?

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but in almost all cases (including this one) doing `while (!fin.feof())` will not work as you expect. Instead do `while (fin >> x)`.

Comment: Note: [`eof` considered harmful](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have a `std::string`; you have an `std::stringstream`. And you can't "print" a stringstream, but you can obtain the `std::string` representation of its buffer, using the `str()` member function.

You probably meant, then:

```
std::cout << buffer.str();
```

There are cleaner ways to do this, but the above will get you started.

As an aside, your loop is wrong. You're checking for EOF too soon.

Comment: Of course... Thanks for help. That worked. What do you mean by checking for EOF too soon? Will changing too `do, while` loop help?

Comment: @Patryk: Actually it might.